# How can I make my divs fully responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

Why my three transparent div in the middle of the page don't work properly when resizing the screen to md, sm and xs. I have 3 offset to the left. How can I make it adaptive? They're supposed to be centered one next to the other. But when I resize the one on the left won't take the whole row... What am I missing?

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="text-center ">ZeoroDegree</h1>
  <h4 class="text-center">Local Weather Application</h4>
  <div id="loc" class="text-center ">Miami FL US</div>
  <div id="date" class="text-center"></div>
  <div id="icon" class="text-center">ICON</div>
  <div class="desc text-center">
    <h4>Clear Sky</h4>
  </div>

  <div id="data" class="row text-center ">
    <div id="temp" class="col-lg-2 offset-3  col-xs-12 transparent text-center box ">
      Temperature: 89 F
    </div>
    <div id="hum" class="col-lg-2 col-xs-12 transparent box ">Humidity: 50%
    </div>
    <div id="wind" class="col-lg-2 col-xs-3 transparent box">Wind: 5mph
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want your col take full width in small device?

Comment: what type of output you need all div in center and one column

Comment: - Duannx yes. I would like to take full row for small devices

Comment: - Bhargav take a look at the code above.. I think is temperature, humidity, wind speed. is there a better way to do this?

Comment: - Bhargav I used divs b/c I think they give me more control over other tags like <p> tags. Do you have any suggestions

Comment: by the way here's the pen I'm working on https://codepen.io/zentech/pen/KqvrEx?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="text-center">ZeoroDegree</h1>
  <h4 class="text-center">Local Weather Application</h4>
  <div id="loc" class="text-center">Miami FL US</div>
  <div id="date" class="text-center"></div>
  <div id="icon" class="text-center">ICON</div>
  <div class="desc text-center">
    <h4>Clear Sky</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="data" class="row text-center">
    <div id="temp" class="col-lg-4 offset-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 transparent text-center box">
      Temperature: 89 F
    </div>
    <div id="hum" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 transparent box">Humidity: 50%
    </div>
    <div id="wind" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 transparent box">Wind: 5mph
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: they're supposed to be one next to the other